# Retrofit onResponse not firing when using a simple checkifUserAlreadyExist php file as Base Url?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am working on this simple app which insert and retrieve data from mysql and I am using Retrofit to send post data to php files which are performing sql operation like saving user data and checking if user already exist.
It works fine when I create an object of User having his/her credentials like name, phone etc but now I am trying to send only one String data which is phone and I want to check if that phone number already exists in database.
Retrofit onResponse method does not being called at all in Call.enqueue and I can't find any reason. Php file is working perfectly as I tested it with a simple html form.
Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code.

ApiInterface.java

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("checkUser.php")
Call<String> checkUser(
        @Field("phone") String phone
);
```

ApiClient.java

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://araincommunity.website/";
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Main Code:

```
public void userAlreadyExist(String phone) {
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<String> call = apiInterface.checkUser(phone);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            alreadyRegistered = response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            alreadyRegistered = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Note: alreadyRegistered is a global boolean variable which is being updated in case of successful response.

Comment: Could it be possible that is the onFailure method the one being called?

Comment: onFailure too is not being called here. It skips to whole Call.enqueue method when it reaches on its first line (call.enqueue). What would be wrong here?

Comment: What I think is happening is that somehow your request fails because of the GsonConverter, you made a Call<String>, is a simple string exactly what you are expecting to get from the server? or is it a model? Could you post what does the JSON response you expect looks like?

Comment: This is what I am expecting if the user with that Phone numberd doesn't exist in database. {"success":false,"message":"Error"}. If user does exists success value will be true and message will be changed according to this.

Comment: What do you suggest in that case, how to achieve this? I need to send one string which is phone number and php file will run query in sql to check whether user with this phone number exists in mysql db or not? How can I get it done using Retrofit?

Comment: Let me write a briefly explanation in the answer section, so you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that your response is not parsed correctly. You pointed out that you are expecting: `{"success":false,"message":"Error"}`, which is a JSON object, and you are using `GsonConverterFactory`, so Retrofit would expect an entity that matches your response definition.

I would try this:

Create a CheckUserResponse class, it would looks something like this:

```
class CheckUserResponse {

     @SerializedName("success") Boolean success;

     @SerializedName("message") String message;

}
```

Then use it in your API call definition, like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("checkUser.php")
Call<CheckUserResponse> checkUser(
    @Field("phone") String phone
);
```

You would need to change your next Callback and Call references also to use this model, but that should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this but no success. You can check my modified code here. https://ibb.co/c1YJ5FY

Comment: is there any useful log in the console that you can share?

Comment: There is none in Errors section. Do you want me to share Vebose logs?

Comment: Yup, everything would help to tryna find a fix :D

Comment: Here. I uploaded it in a text file. https://filebin.net/g6h3fxs3634eyuqp/log.txt?t=tub1sfbd

Comment: I think log is not much helpful. It doesn't show any error or warning about Retrofit. I couldn't find anything in logs related to Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Luis Alonso Paulino Flores helped me alot.
I modified my code and I am sharing it here in case somebody needed it.

ApiInterface.Java

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("checkUser.php")
Call<CheckUser> checkUser(@Field("phone") String phone);
```

ApiClient.Java

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://araincommunity.website/";
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
if (retrofit == null){
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
return retrofit;
}
```

CheckUser.Java //Model Class for Response

```
public class CheckUser {
@Expose
@SerializedName("response")
private String response;

public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(String response) {
    this.response = response;
}
}
```

Main Code:

```
public void userAlreadyExist(final String phone) {
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<CheckUser> call = apiInterface.checkUser(phone);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<CheckUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CheckUser> call, Response<CheckUser> response) {
            pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            etPhone.setEnabled(true);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            Log.e("Rashid Faheem", "Response Code:" + response.code());
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                if (response.body().getResponse().equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){
                    Intent it = new Intent(GetPhoneNumber.this, AlreadyDonor.class);
                    it.putExtra("phone", phone);
                    startActivity(it);
                }else{
                    Intent it = new Intent(GetPhoneNumber.this, GetName.class);
                    it.putExtra("phone", phone);
                    startActivity(it);

                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CheckUser> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

CheckUser.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
require_once("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT phone FROM bloodgroup WHERE phone = '$phone' ";
$response = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$data = mysqli_num_rows($response);
if($data>0){  
$error='ok';
echo json_encode(array('response'=>$error));
}else{  
$error = 'failed';
echo json_encode(array('response'=>$error));    
}
}
?>
```